# Maintain correct SCNNode position in ARKit while walking, without calling run and .resetTracking on each CLLocation update

Tags: ios, core-location, arkit

I'm building a simple navigation app with ARKit. The app shows a pin at a destination, which can be far away or nearby. The user is able to walk toward the pin to navigate.

In my `ARSCNView` I have an `SCNNode` called `waypointNode`, which represents the pin at the destination.

To determine where to place the `waypointNode`, I calculate the `distance` to the destination in meters, and the `bearing` (degrees away from North) to the destination. Then, I create and multiply some transformations and apply them to the node to put it in the proper position.

There's also some logic establish a maximum distance away for the `waypointNode` so it's not too small for the user to see.

This is how I configure the `ARSCNView`, so the axes line up with the real-world compass directions:

```
func setUpSceneView() {
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    configuration.worldAlignment = .gravityAndHeading
    configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal
    session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking])
}
```

Every time the device gets a new CLLocation from CoreLocation, I update the `distance` and `bearing` then call this function to update the position of the `waypointNode`:

```
func updateWaypointNode() {

    // limit the max distance so the node doesn't become invisible
    let distanceLimit: Float = 80

    let translationDistance: Float
    if navigationInfo.distance > distanceLimit {
        translationDistance = distanceLimit
    } else {
        translationDistance = navigationInfo.distance
    }

    // transform matrix to adjust node distance
    let distanceTranslation = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, 0, -translationDistance)

    // transform matrix to rotate node around y-axis
    let rotation = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(-1 * GLKMathDegreesToRadians(Float(navigationInfo.bearing)), 0, 1, 0)

    // multiply the rotation and distance translation matrices
    let distanceTimesRotation = SCNMatrix4Mult(distanceTranslation, rotation)

    // grab the current camera transform
    guard let cameraTransform = session.currentFrame?.camera.transform else { return }

    // multiply the rotation and distance translation transform by the camera transform
    let finalTransform = SCNMatrix4Mult(SCNMatrix4(cameraTransform), distanceTimesRotation)

    // update the waypoint node with this updated transform
    waypointNode.transform = finalTransform
}
```

This works fine when the user first starts the session, and when the user moves less than about 100m.

Once the user covers a significant distance, like over 100m walking or driving, just calling `updateWaypointNode()` is not enough to maintain the proper position of the node at the destination. When walking toward the node, for example, it's possible for the user to eventually reach the node, even though the user has not reached the destination. Note: This incorrect positioning happens while the session open the whole time, not if the session is interrupted.

**As a workaround, I'm also calling `setUpSceneView()` every time the device gets a location update.**

Even though this works OK, it feels wrong to me. It doesn't seem like I should have to call `run` with the `.resetTracking` option every time. I think I might just be overlooking something in my translations. I also see some jumpiness in the camera that seems to happen every time `run` is called when the session is running, so that's less desirable than simply updating translations.

**Is there something different I could do to avoid calling `run` on the session and resetting the tracking every time the device gets a location update?**

Comment: Have you looked into a tool like https://github.com/ProjectDent/ARKit-CoreLocation ?

Comment: @xta yes, I tried using that first, but that framework doesn’t work for what I want to do in my app